# Promote a naive datetime to system timezone

Tags: python, datetime

I have a naïve datetime in hand and I want to promote it to include the system timezone.  I see lots of examples where the timezone is known a priori and the datetime is localized against it.  How do I obtain the local timezone if I don't know it in advance?

```
local_tz = ???
dt = local_tz.localize(naive_time)
```

Comment: You can get the system timezone from `time.timezone` or `time.tzname`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the appropriate `local_tz` by doing:

```
import time
import pytz

local_tz = pytz.timezone(time.tzname[0])
```

EDIT: It appears that `time.tzname[0]` isn't always a name that corresponds to those found in `pytz.all_timezones`

The simplest solution is to use the `tzlocal` package, which uses a number of tricks to find the local timezone from the system, and can also localize for you in place of pytz:

```
import tzlocal

local_tz = tzlocal.get_localzone()
local_tz.localize(naive_time)
```

Comment: This seems to be on the right track, but pytz couldn't create a timezone from that string:  pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'Pacific Standard Time'

Answer (score 0):

Here is as close as I've managed to get:

```
local_tz = dateutil.tz.tzlocal()
timestamp = timestamp.replace(tzinfo=local_tz)
```

Unfortunately local_tz doesn't have a localize() method so I resorted to using replace().